# What's the font used by the England jersey for the World Cup 2014

Tags: font-identification

I would like to know which font is this:

[image]

It's used in the World Cup 2014, in the England jersey. I have searched in http://www.whatfontis.com/ as well as in What The Font but couldn't find a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This font was created by Neville Brody especially for the event (you cannot identify it or find on font sites) and is a part of England's World Cup kit (90£).

[image]